# Cadastro php com angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

Olá!

Tenho o seguinte controller no angular:

```
myApp.controller('cadastrarClienteController', function($scope, $http){
$scope.cadastrarCliente = function () {
$cliente = {
    CliNome: $scope.cli_nome,
    CliTelefone: $scope.cli_telefone,
    CliEmail: $scope.cli_email,
    CliDescricao: $scope.cli_descricao
};

var response = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: baseUrl + "/index.php/Clientes/create",
    data: JSON.stringify($cliente),
    dataType: "json"
});
return response;});
```

Está correto o jeito que estou trabalhando?

`create no php`

```
public function create() {

    if ($this->method == 'POST') {

        $var = json_decode($_POST['cliente']);
        var_dump($var);

        /*$nome = $this->input->post('cli_nome');
        $descricao = $this->input->post('cli_descricao');
        $telefone = $this->input->post('cli_telefone');
        $email = $this->input->post('cli_email');

        $data = array(
            'cli_nome'      => $nome,
            'cli_descricao' => $descricao,
            'cli_telefone'  => $telefone,
            'cli_email'     => $email,
        );
        $res = $this->clientes_model->create_cliente($data);*/
    }
}
```

Não sei o que exatamente fazer dentro desse `if`. Ou seja, como "pegar" os dados que vem por `POST` enviado pelo `angular`.

é no `response` que retorna que deu certo?

Obrigado

Comment: Se está vindo por POST, você já tentou pegar utilizando o $_POST['<variavel>'] ? O que iria para o php seria um JSon, daí você pode tentar pegar usando json_decode.

Comment: faço um `json_decode` e depois um `$_POST`?

Comment: Nesse caso, tente o seguinte:
$var = json_decode($_POST['cliente']);
Daí dê um var_dump na $var pra ver o que aparece.

Comment: Tentei mas não deu certo.. alterei a pergunta para mostrar como estou fazendo

Answer (score -1):

```html
public function create($cli_nome, $cli_telefone, $cli_email, $cli_descricao) {
  /* Restante do código */
}

$cli_nome = $_POST["cli_nome"];
$cli_telefone = $_POST["cli_telefone"];
$cli_email = $_POST["cli_email"];
$cli_descricao = $_POST["cli_descricao"];

create($cli_nome, $cli_telefone, $cli_email, $cli_descricao);
```

Tente fazer a requisição e depois enviar ele para a função como parâmetro.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde.
Então trabalho com o code m formato de API e o front em Angular.
Primeiro tu terá de baixar e integrar ao code a lib desse [link](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver).

Lê bem como funciona, é simples na verdade.
Após isso, lá no angular, tu vai definir a url de enviará a requisição para o code.

No código do code, tu irá receber as informações assim:

```
public function Formulario_post(){

    $nomeCliente = $this->post('cli_nome');
    //outras variáveis
    //segue para as validações e models

}
```

Depois de processar as informações e persistir ou não no banco, tu deverá retornar um código Http dizendo se deu certo ou não. Aconselho a ler esse [link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_status_HTTP) também para poder entender.

Espero ter ajudado.

Oss!